# Android GPS: specify NTP_SERVER for GPS in code

Tags: android, gps, ntp

Hey, what I am doing now is to specify the NTP_SERVER in my application for the GPS LocationProvider to request time, in lieu of reading property from \system\etc\gps.conf, because there's always problem of connecting to north-america.pool.ntp.org from China.
Noting that GpsLocationProvider, the framework class of Android OS, is doing the time-request job with another framework class SNTPClient, how could I be able to override the function or find a way around to assign another ntp address to GPSLocationProvider?

Answer (score -1):

The GPS time provider does not use the an internet server. The GPS needs at least four satellites to be in view to resolve a space-time position (one satellite for each dimension of space and one for a location in time). I would try moving somewhere outside with a clear view of the sky.

Comment: That is not the point, A-GPS uses an approximate time to speed-up the first fix ; this is why it uses NTP.

Comment: Ok I get it. I was under the impression that the goal was a clock correction, not a faster time to fix. In which case you don't necessarily need a network connection. @user741006: What is the goal for using a different NTP server?

Comment: check the source codes of GpsLocationProvider. http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/location/java/com/android/internal/location/GpsLocationProvider.java.shtml

Comment: In China, connection to north-america.pool.ntp.org has been always like a nightmare. I need to redirect the connection to the time server to a close server, like cn.pool.ntp.org.

Comment: If you change the setting to `pool.ntp.org` it will pull a random server.  If you specify a location like `north-america.pool.ntp.org` it makes sure to send a closer server.  There's no guarantee that this server will be online however, but they monitor this pretty closely.  You should however always use multiple NTP servers for this reason, and NTP.org supports numeric prefixes for this, like `0.pool.ntp.org`, `1.pool.ntp.org` or `2.north-america.pool.ntp.org`.  Specifying 2 or 3 servers using this nomenclature will help a lot.  PS I run one of the many ntp.org listed time servers.